# Where is fslint (duplicate file finder) for Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, files, 20.04, filemanager

I tried to install `fslint`

```
:~# apt install fslint
```

and I received

```
Package fslint is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'fslint' has no installation candidate
```

Well, `fslint` was avaliable in Ubuntu 19.10.

In the `fslint` website http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/ shows it is available for Ubuntu.

What happened?
Was it removed from the 20.04 repository?
Or they substituted for another package or name?

Comment: Your link is 404 (not found).

Comment: now the link has been fixed

Answer (score 35):

It is not presented in 20.04 LTS repositories because Python 2 deprecated stuff, but you can install it manually:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/fslint
cd ~/Downloads/fslint
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fslint/fslint_2.46-1_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

and enjoy using it by running `fslint-gui` executable.

---

For 20.10 the solution is a bit longer

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/fslint
cd ~/Downloads/fslint
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi7_3.3-4_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject-2/python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pycairo/python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fslint/fslint_2.46-1_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

---

There's also unofficial [Snap package created recently](https://snapcraft.io/fslint-unofficial), which just packs latest `fslint` version available in Ubuntu 18.04.

```bsh
sudo snap install fslint-unofficial
```

To work with files in external media use `snap connect fslint-unofficial:removable-media`.

Comment: What is the `-p` option for mkdir?

Comment: It means with *parents* - see [`man mkdir`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/mkdir.1.html).

Comment: Is there an alternative to fslint that doesn't require depreciated dependencies?

Comment: For alternatives you can check askubuntu.com/q/3865/66509 . From my experience Komparator was great too, but is not available after 18.04 LTS. I like fslint for its simplicity and that it is was in repository until 20.04 LTS, in practice I do not see any alternative for it on modern Ubuntu. We need to wait fslint to be ported to Python 3. Possible alternative maybe [`rmlint-gui`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=rmlint-gui&searchon=names) but I did not tested it myself.

Comment: Is installing obsolete dependencies likely to conflict with other packages in 20.04, or is it safe to do so?

Comment: It is safe way to use.

Comment: For completeness' sake: Could you please also add a brief instruction on how to "undo" the commands (e.g. `sudo apt-get remove .. `); thanks!

Comment: There is nothing special here. All these packages are regular deb-packages. So they can be removed using `apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude` or Synaptic. In Aptitude and Synaptic these packages will be marked as obsolete or locally installed. So you can sort them from others.

Comment: Any educated guess when this workaround will no longer be necessary (e.g. is anyone working on updating `fslint`) ?

Comment: You have to subscribe to the issue on Github https://github.com/pixelb/fslint/issues/168 and ask there.

Comment: The app being Gtk2 and Glade based is a bigger issue than Python 2 - it'll take a chunk of work to do that porting, whereas porting to Python 3 is pretty easy.   The code style shows it's age too, a lot of norms around python coding hadn't been decided 14 years ago.

Comment: @PatrickConwell Czkawka is a clone of FSlint written in Rust, but doesn't seem to work as well yet https://github.com/pixelb/fslint/issues/173

Comment: 20.10 instructions don't work: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dh-python : Breaks: python
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.` Actually I removed `dh-python` and it worked. It didn't remove any other packages so I guess that was cruft from some older install

Comment: @endolith Can't reproduce on fresh 20.10 VM, you have had some local problems.

Answer (score 14):

[czkawka](https://qarmin.github.io/czkawka/) is a modern clone written in Rust, which has the same UI and some more features. I can definitely recommend that one.

According to their own benchmarks it is even 10 times faster than fslint

Comment: I installed the snap for Ubuntu: it looks nice but the action buttons do not perform any action

Comment: I only installed the deb from their ppa, which works flawlessly. Maybe it is a permission issue related to snap?

Comment: In my experience snaps that need disck access don't work without classic confinement, and even then probably not. But non-snap czkawka is working great for me! It's blazing fast compared to fslint, and improves the usability in some areas.

Answer (score 12):

An issue has been opened about it on the official github. Looks like obsolete dependencies are the cause here.

https://github.com/pixelb/fslint/issues/168

Comment: I love the way that issue points right back here...

Answer (score 1):

The following worked again today for me to get the very ultimate **fslint 2.47** in a fresh 20.04.4 (from [forum.ubuntu-fr.org](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=22387794#p22387794) don't worry with errors, we fix them on the walk):

```
mkdir -p ~/Documents/fslint/pygtk
cd ~/Documents/fslint/pygtk
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-glade2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f

cd ..
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/pixelb/fslint.git fslint-2.47
cd fslint-2.47
sudo apt install debhelper
dpkg-buildpackage -I.git -rfakeroot -tc
sudo dpkg -i ../fslint_2.47-1_all.deb

cd ../..
sudo apt purge git debhelper 
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

Then once done and tested with **fslint-gui** you can:

```
rm -rf ~/Documents/fslint
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a package named [rmlint](https://github.com/sahib/rmlint) in the repo of letest Ubuntu releases. Its also having a gui to find duplicate files.