# How do I: #1 increase my reputation points, and #2 run fslint in Ubuntu 20.04 after installing it?

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, duplicate-files

It is really annoying that I cannot add comments or follow-on questions to topics without enough "reputation points".  I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and now my fslint won't work.

I found a discussion about fslint here, but I cannot ask a simple followup question.

How do I:

#1 increase my reputation points, and

#2 run fslint in Ubuntu 20.04 after installing it?  (see thread below)

[Where is fslint (duplicate file finder) for Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233710/where-is-fslint-duplicate-file-finder-for-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Your first question belongs on [meta.askubuntu.com](https://meta.askubuntu.com) where it is likely a duplicate - see [How can I increase my reputation on Ask Ubuntu?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/495/how-can-i-increase-my-reputation-on-ask-ubuntu)

Comment: Could you use `hardlink`?

Comment: Asking a good question gets upvote worth 10 points each